# big chart of supported assemblies for PCL?

Tags: xamarin, portable-class-library

I'm attempting my first crack at a PCL, targeting Windows, WinPhone and Xamarin. I'm finding that some very basic things, like Package and SortedDictionary, won't import (claims they don't exist). I'm sure this exists in Windows and Xamarin (Mono), so I'm a bit lost as to why my Imports doesn't work. Perhaps it's because Xamarin included Silverlight and SL doesn't support it?

Can anyone point me to a big list of supported imports that might help? Or perhaps a comparison tool? There's a scanner tool on the Xamarin web site, but it appears to be broken. I can't find a list on the Xamarin site, and my google-fu has once again failed me.

Answer (score 1):

Here are [some features listed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#features), albeit not including Xamarin. OTOH Xamarin is very feature rich and it is unlikely that something is missing because of it. More likely the culprits are Silverlight and WP Silverlight.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the [.NET Portability Analyzer](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/08/06/leveraging-existing-code-across-net-platforms.aspx).